# WPF ReactiveUI ComboBox Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, reactiveui

I have a WPF ComboBox bound to a ReactiveList and a registered view for a model `(IViewFor<MyModel>)`, so it correctly shows the list when the combobox is opened.

The problem is that the selected value is not shown in the combobox when it is closed.

**XAML**

```
<DockPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="SourceSystemDatabases" />
</DockPanel>
```

**Binding**

```
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.SourceDatabases, view => view.SourceSystemDatabases.ItemsSource);
```

**Opened combobox**

[image: Opened combobox]

**Closed combobox with no text**

[image: closed combobox with no next]

Comment: Did you define a custom ComboBoxItem style or ItemTemplate or why are the items green?

Comment: @mm8 Yes, I have registered a control for the model with `container.Register<IViewFor<MyModel>, MyModelComboBoxItemTemplate>();` as ReactiveUI overrides item templates. I expect it to use the same template for the selected item rendering when combobox is closed.

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @mm8 what exactly is not clear in a question?

Comment: How MyModelComboBoxItemTemplate is defined for example.

Comment: Do you also have a binding for the SelectedIndex. If that is incorrectly done then it may always be set to -1 nomatter what you select in the drop down.

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45133895/104877