# Binding ReactiveList to ComboBox couldn't find view error

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

I am binding a ReactiveList to a ComboBox in the view code-behind and get the error **System.Exception: 'Couldn't find view for 'Value1'.'**.

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class SourceItem 
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public ReactiveList<SourceItem> SourceList { get; } = new ReactiveList<SourceItem>();
    public SourceItem SelectedSourceItem { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        SourceList.Add(new SourceItem() {Name = "Value1"});
    }
}
```

**View.xaml**

```
<ComboBox Name="Source"/>
```

**View.cs**

```
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.SourceList, x => x.Source.ItemSource);
this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.SelectedSourceItem, x => x.Source.SelectedItem);
```

Is there a simple way to force `ToString()` to be used for the display values?

Comment: You need DataTemplate for your ComboBox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular `Binding` will automatically work without a `DataTemplate`. It will generate a `DataTemplate` to display a `string` representation of the provided data.

RxUI bindings does not work that way; you have to provide a `DataTemplate` for them to work:

```
<ComboBox Name="Source">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

When just using `{Binding}` it should fall back to calling `ToString()` on your class. Alternatively you can of course tell it to bind to the `Name` property manually:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Comment: I'm using the `{Binding Name}` method and I can't seem to get it to work. Also using a stylized ComboBox from MaterialDesignInXAML if that might be causing issues?