# WPF ReactiveUI ListBox populates with bound ItemsSource but ComboBox does not

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui, material-design-in-xaml

I have a `ListBox` that correctly populates with an array of an object. This is using a `DataTemplate` with the `DataType` set to my object and a `TextBlock` with `Text="{Binding Name}". This works correctly and I'm not having issues with it populating.

My problem is with a `ComboBox` that I'm seemingly populating the same way. I set the `DataType` and `{Binding Name}` (to a different object type than the `ListBox`. The ViewModel structure and code-behind binding are extremely similar for each one. I'm having a hell of a time trying to figure out how to get it to populate.

I'm also using MaterialDesignInXAML for the ComboBox with `Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintComboBox}"`. I don't think that should matter, just adding it here in case it does.

I've looked into some questions with answers that should cover this, but I can't seem to get it to work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56782702/9452665

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45133895/9452665

Here's the relevant `ListBox` code:

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="NavigationItemsListBox" Margin="0 16 0 16" SelectedIndex="0">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ScrollBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignScrollBarMinimal}" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="model:NavigationItem">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="32 0 32 0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

```cs
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel,
    viewModel => viewModel.NavigationItems,
    view => view.NavigationItemsListBox.ItemsSource)
    .DisposeWith(disposableRegistration);
```

`MainWindowViewModel` has an array of `NavigationItem`s.

Here's the relevant `ComboBox` code:

```xml
<ComboBox Name="DataTypeComboBox" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintComboBox}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Data Type" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="models:DatasheetType">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

```cs
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel,
    viewModel => viewModel.DatasheetTypeItems,
    view => view.DataTypeComboBox.ItemsSource)
    .DisposeWith(disposableRegistration);
```

`DataImportViewModel` has an array of `DatasheetType`s.

Tried a bunch of things but can't seem to get the `ComboBox` to actually show any items in it.

Comment: The problem was I was not assigning the view model in the code behind for the usercontrol hosting the ComboBox.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that there was no assignment of ViewModel to the view model in the UserControl code-behind hosting the ComboBox. After adding the assignment it works.

```cs
ViewModel = new DataImportViewModel();
```